# Bootstrap Popover with AngularJS & input

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

```
<select ng-model="dropdownlist" ng-options="x.item as x.item for x in list | unique:'item'">
</select>

<a data-toggle="popover" data-title="Add New Item" data-container="body" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="AddNewItem">Add New</a>
<!-- This doesn't work -->
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <input ng-model="addMe" placeholder="Item">
  <button ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>
<!-- But this does (just removed the popover div) -->
<input ng-model="addMe" placeholder="Item">
<button ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ywkuzpvm/42/)

I'm trying to add an item to a dropdown list with an input from a popover using angular. It works when I take the popover out, but not with it.

Comment: Im looking into it, but I would advise you to look into angular-bootstrap, which is a wrapper for these bootstrap directives. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: You'll likely save a lot of time if you take Devin's advice.  The most likely issue is that your popover code is not being compiled properly because of your jquery.  You can look into `$compile` but I've never tried to use it mixed with jquery so I'm not sure off the top of my head exactly what working code will look like.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to get it working with angular-ui bootstrap. Here's the working JSFIDDLE. http://jsfiddle.net/ywkuzpvm/282/